# How can I view iOS 10.x system log?

Tags: ios, logging

We are developing an iPhone/iPad app that will run on iOS 10.x. Apparently Apple has done away with the system log and replaced it with "Unified Logging". These devices are NOT "jail broken". How can I view this log either from a Mac / PC or on the iPad itself?

Thank you!

Comment: From your Mac you can use console or instruments

Comment: GIJOW, thank you for the response. Can you elaborate on HOW I would do that from my Mac?

Comment: CMD + Space bar will show you spolight, type console and you will see the app. For instruments, it comes with xcode, same procedure if you have xcode and type instruments

Answer (score 3):

GIJOW should have added this as an answer - upvote his comment:

- plug your device into a mac via USB
- CMD + Space to open spotlight search, type console and open it (close Console first if it was already opened from a previous session with a simulator)
- You will see a list of Devices for which real-time logs will be displayed

Comment: There should be an upvote button next to the comment - maybe there is a reputation limit you need to reach first.